# Can you the number of NFT's that can be minted in a transaction?

Tags: nft, minting

I wanted to understand if you could place a hard limit on the number of tokens minted under a policy.
I've scanned the docs and the policy.script only seems to control permission and the amount of time before the policy is locked.

I'm wondering if this is possible, and if not - what stops NFT creators just minting more than they say they will?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to specify the limit for a given native asset in the policy.

Only, once the policy is `timelock`ed, you have the guarantee that the NFT creator does not mint or burn the NFTs.

Answer (score 1):

With a Plutus script, you can absolutely limit the number by ensuring not more than a certain number has been minted by putting it into the validator.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Lars Lecture 5 ... https://youtu.be/SsaVjSsPPcg?t=2471
It explains everything very clearly!